# Extrair arquivo XML de um arquivo ZIP

Tags: node.js

O codigo abaixo faz uma requisição a um WebService que me retorna um arquivo XML dentro de um arquivo ZIP.

```
myXMLText = ''
request({
    url: "http://webservice.newrastreamentoonline.com.br/",
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "content-type": "application/xml",  // <--Very important!!!
    },
    body: myXMLText
    }, function (error, response, body){
    //console.log(body);
})
.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('rastreamento.zip'))
```

Só que em vez de salvar o arquivo, eu queria abrir ele, pegar o arquivo XML e passar de parametro para uma outra funcao que converte o XML em Json.

```
var result = convert.xml2js(xml,{alwaysChildren: true});
```

Como eu posso pegar o conteudo do arquivo e salvar na variavel xml da funcao de baixo para fazer a conversao?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Fiz do jeito "dificil".

Depois de baixar o arquivo, descompactei, abri ele, li o conteudo do xml.

Deu certo no fim.

```
request({
    url: "http://webservice.xxxxxxx.com.br/",
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "content-type": "application/xml",  // <--Very important!!!
    },
    body: myXMLText
    }, function (error, response, body){
    
    })
.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('onix.zip')) //salvo o arquivo zip
.on('finish',()=>{
    console.log('Arquivo baixado do WebService')
    fs.createReadStream('onix.zip')
    .pipe(unzipper.Parse())
    .on('entry', function (entry) {
      console.log('Descompactando arquivo')
      const fileName = entry.path;
      const type = entry.type; // 'Directory' or 'File'
      const size = entry.vars.uncompressedSize; // There is also compressedSize;
      console.log(fileName)
      entry.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('output/onix.xml')
                .on('error', err => console.log('error', err.message))
                .on('ready',()=>{
                    console.log('Lendo arquivo')
                    fs.createReadStream('output/onix.xml')
                    .on('data', function (chunk) { 
                        //console.log('aqui4')
                        xml+=chunk.toString()
                        //console.log(xml); 
                    })
                    .on('end', function (chunk) {
                        //console.log(xml) 
                        console.log('Convertendo de XML p/ JSON')
                        result = convert.xml2js(xml,{alwaysChildren: true}); // or convert.xml2json(xml, options)\
                        
                        console.log('Preparando SQL STATMENT | '+result.elements[0].elements.length+' LINHAS')
                        sql='';
                        for(i=0;i<result.elements[0].elements.length;i++){//trocar o 5 por result.elements[0].elements.length
                            table=''
                            value=''
                            for(j=0;j<result.elements[0].elements[i].elements.length;j++){
                                //sql += (result.elements[0].elements[i].elements[j].name);
                                //console.log(JSON.parse(result.elements[0].elements[i].elements[j].elements));                        
                                try{
                                    if(result.elements[0].elements[i].elements[j].name.toLowerCase()=='rod' || result.elements[0].elements[i].elements[j].elements[0].text==null){
                        
                                    }else{
                                        table += result.elements[0].elements[i].elements[j].name.toLowerCase()+(j==(result.elements[0].elements[i].elements.length-1)?'':',')
                                        value += "'"+result.elements[0].elements[i].elements[j].elements[0].text.replace('\'',' ').replace('true','1').replace('false','0')+"'"+(j==(result.elements[0].elements[i].elements.length-1)?'':',')
                                    }                                    
                                }catch{
                        
                                }
                            }
                            sql += 'INSERT INTO onixsat (' + table + ') VALUES (' + value + ')'
                            sql+=';\n'
                        }
                        console.log('Executando SQL')
                        //console.log(sql)
                        
                    })
                })
                
            )
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma possível solução para este problema é não salvar o arquivo no zip e fazer a conversão direto para json antes de criar o `zip`.

Com a lib [xml2json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml2json) pode-se conseguir o resultado desejado.
Utilizando o seu código seria:

```
const parser = require('xml2json');
myXMLText = ''
request({
    url: "http://webservice.newrastreamentoonline.com.br/",
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "content-type": "application/xml",  // <--Very important!!!
    },
    body: myXMLText
    }, function (error, response, body){
        if (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
        const myjson = parser.toJson(body);
        //console.log(myjson);
})
```

Repare que eu meu código não fiz o fluxo de transformar o `xml` em `zip`. Colocando o resultado direto dentro da variável `myjson`.